# Type error in Python in classes and objects

Tags: python

```
class Student:
  def __inint__(self,id,name):
    self.id=id
    self.name=name

s1=Student(10,"Aman")
s1.id
```

Comment: `"__inint__" != "__init__"`

Comment: Also, `id` is a bad choice for a variable name, because it's a built-in function. Try something like `_id` or `identifier`.

Answer (score 3):

It's `__init__`  , not `__inint__`.
Your IDE might have tips that can remind you.